# glPointSize equivalent in DirectX 11

Tags: windows-phone-8, hlsl, directx-11, direct3d11

I'm rendering a starfield composed from points(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_POINTLIST). If a point get closer to the camera I make it double the size. That worked well with OpenGL 1.x using glPointSize(2.0f)
Is there a way to achieve this with DirectX 11 on Windows Phone 8?
What I need is a way to make a rendered point appear bigger on some custom value.

Any thought is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no native sprite type in D3D11.  Your best bet is to use instancing with a single quad VB and a per-instance point VB.  You'd scale by dividing the quad point deltas by the view depth, or applying a standard perspective projection matrix (though the latter would also cause the points themselves to converge at higher distances).

Comment: That or render points from a single VB and use a geometry shader to turn them into quads, though I'm not sure how it compares performance-wise.

Comment: @Trillian Performance will be similar but most phones are `FEATURE_LEVEL_9_3` so no geometry shaders.

Comment: Right, no geometry shader on feature level 9_3 I checked it previously

Comment: Also instancing is only supported from 9_3, so if you plan to support 9_2 or 9_1, this will not work.